# Making a shortcut for compiling in C

Tags: neovim, terminal

I've changed my code a million times and can't get it right.

I want to compile the file I have open with whatever its name is minus the `.c` that comes after and I want to do it on a second terminal to see any errors in the code and fix them.

Right now, I'm getting an error on line 24, "undefined variable: gcc" which is one of the many errors I've gotten. Moving around code and using different ways to pass the command to the vim.cmd() function seems to give various errors, from saying that fileName is an undefined value or nil or an assortment of other errors.

```lua
local function get_file_name(file)
    return file:match("^.+/(.+)$")
end

local function finalCommand()
    local currentFile = vim.fn.expand("%:p")
    local FileName = get_file_name(currentFile)
    local FileName2 = string.sub(FileName, 1, -3)
    local x = "!gcc -o ".. FileName2 .." ".. FileName

    return x
end

local function gcc()
    vim.cmd("vsplit | terminal")
    local command = ":wincmd l"
    vim.cmd(command)
    local command2 = finalCommand()
    vim.cmd("call jobsend(b:terminal_job_id, ".. command2 ..")")
    local command3 = ':wincmd h'
    vim.cmd(command3)
end

vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>gcc", function ()
    return gcc()
end)
```

Comment: May be could you explain what is not yet working with your actual code. It will be useful to be sure we reproduce your problem.

Comment: Just want to make sure you already know that `:make foo` will do 99% of what you want. It automatically finds `foo.c`, compiles it, and presents any errors in a window inside vim.

Comment: @pipe i will try this as soon as possible, thank you for the feedback

Comment: Yeah, checkout `:help :make`, the surrounding document, and `:help 30.1`

Answer (score 1):

I do believe that using `:make` is a better option but in case you would like to understand what was wrong with your code here is an adaptation of your code:

```lua
function finalCommand()
    local x = "gcc -o ".. vim.fn.expand("%:r") .." ".. vim.fn.expand("%:n")

    return x
end

function gcc()
    local command2 = finalCommand()
    vim.cmd("vsplit | terminal")
    vim.cmd("call jobsend(b:terminal_job_id, '" .. command2 .. "')")
    local command3 = ':wincmd h'
    vim.cmd(command3)
end

vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>gcc", function ()
    gcc()
end)
```